# Como acrescentar mais valores em um matriz numpy?

Tags: python, matriz, numpy

Estou fazendo um programa em python que usa matrizes, estou usando o numpy para fazê-las, mas está dando o seguinte problema: eu faço a matriz no intuito de guardar vários valores, mas ela guarda apenas um. Eu estava fazendo primeiro uma lista e dps convertendo para array usando np.array(), mas queria fazer de uma outra forma, será que teria como? Segue abaixo meu programa:

```
import numpy as np                          #
import math                                 #               importando bibliotecas para criação das matrizes e cálculos com 
                                            #               números reais, respectivamente.

n1=n2=1                                     #               definindo constantes                                    
pi = math.pi                                #
M = 200 
                                            #
gama1 = 2/3                                                        #
b1 = math.sqrt(gama1) / (1+math.sqrt(1-gama1))                     #

gama2 = 2/3                                                        #   definindo os valores de b1 e b2                                               #
b2 = math.sqrt(gama2) / (1+math.sqrt(1-gama2))                     #

for l in range(1,M+1):
  for c in range(1,n1+1):
    w1 = np.array([b1*math.sqrt(1/(pi*(M+1)))*math.sin((l*c*pi)/(M+1))])  # adicionando valor na lista
  for c in range(1,n2+1):
    w2 = np.array([b2*math.sqrt(1/(pi*(M+1)))*math.sin((l*(n1+c)*pi)/(M+1))])  # adicionando valor na lista
```

no caso as matrizes são w1 e w2, e ao invés de aparecer uma matriz 1x200, mostra uma matrz 1x1

Comment: é pq a cada loop você define a variável novamente. Então no final você fica só com uma lista. Você pode usar `np.append` para apensar a lista a cada loop.

Comment: não entendi como usar essa função, eu usei no programa,mas não deu certo. Poderia dar um exemplo?

Comment: Eu respondi. Mas, por favor, note a quantidade de informação na sua pergunta e no seu código que não se relaciona com a questão. Procure deixar na pergunta apenas o essencial. Veja um guia aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-completo-e-verific%c3%a1vel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema do seu código é que, a cada vez que o loop passa, ele cria a linha novamente. Por isso você fica com apenas uma linha no final.

Uma matriz é, basicamente, uma lista de listas, então você pode usar o método `append` para apensar cada linha em cada iteração do loop. Exemplo:

```py
import numpy as np

linha1=[1,0,0]
linha2=[0,1,0]
linha3=[0,0,1]
linhas=[linha1,linha2, linha3]
matriz=[]

for linha in linhas:
    matriz.append(linha)
```

A variável `matriz` aqui já é uma matriz, mas para ter acesso a metódos matemáticos para transformação e análise da matriz, recomendo usar `np.matrix` do numpy:

```py
M=np.matrix(matriz)

print(M)
```

```
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]]
```

Por xemplo, você pode inverter a matriz, usando:

```
M.I
```

Que, nesse caso, retorna a própria matriz identidade, como se sabe.